# Questions about Java code styles

Tags: java, syntax, coding-style

So I have seen a lot of different coding styles, but I'm only going to talk about two big ones. I use a style where I just name everything like their class name when used in a general sense, like this:

```
String str = "This is some text";
```

But over at [Java Practices](http://www.javapractices.com/home/HomeAction.do), I see a style where they will put an 'I' in front of Interfaces class names, or they put 'f' or 'a' in front of object names. Take this snippet from ["Don't subclass JDialog or JFrame"'](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=962B2D60C852C9AAAA9F8E90BBECF9BB?Id=228):

```
/**
  Constructor.

  <P>Called when adding a new {@link Movie}.
*/
MovieView(JFrame aParent) {
    fEdit = Edit.ADD;
    buildGui(aParent, "Add Movie");
    fStandardDialog.display();
}
```

Why do programmers code in this style? Do a lot of people use it? And also, do professional programmers use this style?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Shades of bad [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) practices. I think most frown on this sort of notation.

Comment: Înstead of writing the fact that you have a question you should place the question itself in the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This my personal opinion.

I prefer not to use prefixes on interface (or anything else for that matter). I just prefer to call it what it is. Interfaces are meant to represent an object (or part of it) without making any implication towards it's actual implementation.

Say you have a Car interface. And AudiA4 could be an implementation of that car. If you just bought a new Audi A4, you say, "I bought a new AudiA4" to those you think care about the kind of car you bought. To others, you can say "I bought a new Car". Certainly, you never say, I bought a new IAudiA4 or a new ICar.

The `JFrame` naming came about because it's a Swing Frame and Swing came after AWT (the original Java windowing toolkit, which already had a Frame class). Since both AWT and Swing where available at the same time, they used the 'J' prefix to demarcate the toolkits (note that JFrame extends Frame, btw). They could have called it SwingFrame but the 'J' prefix was apparently a good choice to represent the Swing package. So basically this prefix is just a naming choice, not a convention similar to the 'I' for interfance (or Impl suffix for implementations you see sometimes as well)

My point is you always have to name your classes and interface according to exactly what they represent. No more, no less. No point having a CarImpl class. Who cares that it's an implementation. Which implementation is it? Why does it need its own class? What more do I get when I use a CarImpl? What happens when I make a second implementation, I call it CarImpl2? All this is very constraining and doesn't bring much value.

Call it what it is. That's the only rule I'd set forth.

All this being said, the Eclipse project, amongst many others, does indeed use the I-for interface notation ([WIKI](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Naming_Conventions)). But it's their choice. I've seen professionals use it as well. I don't like it, but generally speaking, I respect the team's naming convention.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detail there. That helps a lot :) +1

Comment: I never understood the choice by many to use the `Impl` suffix on implementation classes in Java when there's the `Bean` suffix. `CarBean` reads much better than `CarImpl` (unless you're not a Java coder, then beans and ketchup) also even with namespaces you may still have to differentiate the implementation's name from the interface with a suffix e.g `public interface Car {...}` - the interface, `public class CarBean implements Car {...}` - the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a book about such things - Code Complete by Steve McConnell

Comment: @whowantsakookie: That book happens to be one of the best books on the philosophy and practice of code construction and one of my favorite programming books, one you would not regret reading and taking to heart. You may want to reconsider your comment above.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok, but where did my comment go? :\ I know it's a good book, but that's not what I was looking for.

Comment: @whowantsakookie: a moderator must have removed your comment. It was a bit on the rude side to be frank.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oh, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but the only universal convention I've seen when naming Java variables is using Camel-Case notation, that's regarding the format of the name.

As for the name itself, I've always found useful to name the variables according to what they actually are. In your `String` example, although you mention this would be in a general purpose variable, I would still give it a more meaningful name, like:

```
String message = "This is some text";
```

Or:

```
String msg = "This is some text";
```

Some of the Java libraries I've seen source code from tend to be quite verbose when naming variables, others just use single letter names when the variable is used in a reduced context:

```
public Rectangle setLocation(Point p) {
    return setLocation(p.x(), p.y());
}
```

I think the main goal when naming variables (or anything else for that matter) is always to communicate in the best way possible the intent of what you were trying to do.

Comment: I completely agree with you there. Like when you make a `BufferedReader`, you don't call it `br`, you call it something like `saveFileLoader` or something.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is sometimes referred to as "Hungarian notation", though it's not "Hungarian" in the truest sense of the term.

Basically, the idea is to differentiate between different classes of variables -- instance variables, local variables, parameters, et al.  This serves two basic purposes:

1. It helps avoid name collisions, where, say, there might naturally (using "descriptive" variable naming) be an instance variable `ralphsLeftFoot` and a local variable `ralphsLeftFoot`.  Using a prefix allows the two to co-exist, and, especially in languages where the local might (without warning message) "hide" the instance variable, prevents unintended changes in semantics from such collisions.
2. It makes the scope of variables obvious, so that, during maintenance, one does not accidentally assume that a local variable has instance scope or vice-versa.

Is this approach worthwhile?  Many developers use a subset of the scheme, apparently to good effect.  For instance, many Objective-C developers will name the instance variable behind a "property" with a leading "_" character, to clearly differentiate between the two and to avoid accidentally using the instance variable when the property was intended.

Likewise, many developers in a number of languages will prefix instance variables with a letter (often "m") to differentiate them from "normal" local/parameter variables.

What's probably most important is to pick a style that you (and your team) likes and stick with it.  If the team likes the prefixes then use the prefixes.  If the team prefers something else, stick with that.  Of course, changing preferences, when a better choice is "revealed" to you, is OK, but don't switch back and forth willy-nilly.

Comment: Thanks, I usually see the prefixes in the higher scoped variables. That explains a lot. +1

Comment: If you are programming Java, you should probably stick to the common Java coding style, which is no Hungarian notation.

Comment: There is no "common Java coding style".

Answer (score 1):

Code styles help make it easier for developers to read and understand each others code. [Java conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) prescribe the use of short and descriptive identifiers, but unfortunately short and descriptive cannot always be achieved together so you may have to compromise shortness for clarity hence:  `atmosPres` - still clear but short, `atmosphericPressure` - this can't be mistaken, `atm` - because everyone just knows ATM, right?, `ap` - WTF?

I first encountered the practice of prefixing variable names with a three letter type identifier while developing programs in C# - it helps the reader know what data type is contained in a variable without having to look for its declaration (due to short memory or maybe laziness?). Arrays are also prefixed with `I` e.g `IList` to distinguish them from other data types (and for what purpose, I just dunno).

For me, the worst code conventions are in C++ (if indeed there are any at all) - there's a mix of case types for data types and variables, conflicting method and function naming styles and endless cryptic abbreviation which all make it hard for non-regular C++ coders to read and understand C++ code.

Comment: I agree with you. Compromises can only be taken to a certain level. +1

Answer (score -1):

> So I have seen a lot of different coding styles, but I'm only going to
>   talk about two big ones. I use a style where I just name everything
>   like their class name when used in a general sense, like this:
>
> String str = "This is some text";

That is awful.  Imagine if someone were reading your code, trying to understand what it was doing, and they came across a variable named `str`.  It doesn't convey any meaning to the person who has to read this code as to your intentions.

Conventions are used by and for people to improve readability, and thus the overall quality of software.  Without a convention, any project that has more than one developer will suffer from varying styles that will only hurt the readability of the code.  If you want to know what professionals do, look around on the internet for various [conventions](http://code.google.com/p/java-coding-standards/wiki/Introduction).

Comment: "I use a style where I just name everything like their class name **when used in a general sense**,"

Comment: OP care to comment on your down vote?

Comment: "...forgive me if I ask stupid questions!"  I guess no more needs to be said...

Comment: I am talking about using this style **in a general sense**. I am talking about when you are giving an example to your friend, one who may or may not know Java, and are explaining an object to him. Showing him the basics. Things like that, when the object has no real purpose.

Comment: Even when a variable is written for **illustrative** purposes, it should follow some sort of *consistent* and *readable* naming *convention*.

Comment: That's true, but what if you were just explaining an object to a friend? Giving a basic name? There would be no reason to give a descriptive name.

Comment: Why would that justify naming your variable poorly???

Comment: It would not. What if you had this conversation:
Friend: Hey, what's a String?
You: Oh, a String is an object to hold text and stuff!
Friend: Cool, can you give me an example?
You: Yeah! `String str = "This is some text";`

Comment: Whatever.  Look at your original question - are any of these qualifications written in there?  Really - it doesn't matter though.  Good luck with your programming!

Comment: Thanks! But I didn't give you a -1 because you insulted my code. I gave you a -1 because first, you did not even answer the question, but instead went on to criticize me over a simple variable. Hope you understand.